# Hibernate issues with MySQL: 'unable to create requested service'

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jdbc, jar

I am just starting out using Hibernate (using the Hibernate 5.0.2 found on source-forge).

I am using MySQL as my database. I am just starting out, and I’m following [this course to start learning Hibernate](http://sourabhsoni.com/how-to-use-hibernate-4-with-mysql/). I believe I have followed every single step to the dot. In nearly all hibernate examples that I found, I see that org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder is deprecated, so the tutorials are out of date.

So instead I import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder and use that and there are no compiler issues. My steps: I started up the local server, then I created the Java Project, and added the necessary jar files to the class path (all the required in hibernate 5.0.2, and the MySQL connectorJ). Then, I create a package in the /src folder, and put both the example ‘Employee.java’ class, and the ‘MainClass.java’ in that package. Outside of the package I put the employee.hm.xml, and the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the /src folder.

Then I run the MainClass.java file, and here is the stack trace:

```
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.2.Final}
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb]
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 08, 2015 1:30:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
```

And here is the error it gives me:

> **Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment**

That’s all the information, no ‘Cause’ like I sometimes see in the stack trace.

The classes and xml files can be found on the website I posted above. I literally copied and pasted (except for the Password, and as I noted the StandardServiceRegistryBuilder).

If you would like me to post my actual classes and files, I would be happy too, but just note it will be the same as the website.  This is my first time using Hibernate, and I don’t understand why it isn’t working. If you have any questions please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Wow never mind. Sorry for bothering you. The tutorial stated I did not need to have the hibernatedb database created in MySQl, but it turns out all I needed to do was create the hibernatedb in MySQL. I had done this before, but it must have been a different configuration than I had used before because I never have gotten this to work. I guess posting this and looking into it in more depth helped me though. Thanks!